# How to run XBAP (WPF Web) applications on newer versions of chrome

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xbap

I have a few thousand applications written in C # WPF Web (.xbap). I need these applications to run on Google Chrome on newer versions as well.

I saw in some posts in 2014 ways to do this by copying some Firefox dlls to the Chrome application folder (C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application) but in the new versions this directory no longer exists ....

Any way to do that in the middle of 2020? ahahah :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run xbap application directly with Google Chrome, but you can run it with  chrome extension called [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) may this will help you.